# Differentiation of a function at a specific point

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

There are two functions

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sqrt{2x+1}-1}x&\text{ if }x\ne0\\
        1&\text{ if }x=0\end{cases}$$and
$$h (x) =  x^9 - 6x^8 -2x^7 + 12x^6 +x^4 -7x^3 + 6x^2 + x-7.$$

Now if $g(x)$ is continuous at $x =0$ then we have to prove that $g'(0)$ is equal to $\frac12h(6)$.

I tried and got $g'(0)=1$.

But I am not able to comment on $h(x)$.

Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $h(6)/2=-\frac{1}{2}$, so we need to find $g'(0)$.

Expanding by the binomial theorem we have $\sqrt{2x+1}=1+x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{x}+\dots$, so $(\sqrt{2x+1}-1)/x=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\dots$. Hence $\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=\frac{g(x)-1}{x}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{2}+\dots$ which tends to $-\frac{1}{2}$ as $x\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$h(6)=6^9-6\cdot 6^8 -2 \cdot 6^7 + 2 \cdot 6 \cdot 6^6 + 6^4-7 \cdot 6^3 + 6 \cdot 6^2 +6 -7 =$$
$$=(6^9-6\cdot 6^8) -12(  6^6 - 6^6) + 6^3(6-7+1) +6 -7 = 0 - 12 \cdot 0+6^3 \cdot 0 -1 = -1$$

so that $h(6)/2 \neq 1$. You must have done some mistake.

Comment: Can we comment any thing on h(x) if it is bounded or not

Comment: $h(x)$ is a polynomial. Have you ever seen a bounded polynomial?

Comment: if its range and domain is real number

Comment: Sorry I got it. It cannot be bounded

Comment: How is this related to your question? Polynomials are defined everywhere, and are never bounded, but I don't see how this helps.

Comment: i am asking for knowledge